# What is the grammar rule for this Haskell code?

Tags: haskell, syntax

I have basic knowledge of Haskell (so forgive me if my question looks trivial for Haskellers here) and recently have been looking into the syntax of Haskell. In the [Haskell 2010 report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html#x17-18000010.5) there is only one place that keyword "type" is used:

```
topdecl ::=  "type" simpletype "=" type
```

And as can be seen, there is always a `"="` is required. In one Haskell file, I see this piece of code:

```
type Key m :: *
```

taken from [TrieMap.hs](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/compiler/coreSyn/TrieMap.hs) line 61.

which doesn't comply to the rule. I suspect this is a GHC extension or something
similar. Can someone point out to me which grammar rule this piece of code conforms to?
BTW, I didn't find the grammar rules for extensions and had to guess many of them, are there documented somewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's an [associated type family declaration](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/type-families.html#assoc-decl), part of the `TypeFamilies` extension.

It's basically used inside a class declaration to tell that the class has a type associated to each instance of it.

I don't remember any place that has nicely laid out BNF grammar for extensions, although I did once find [GHC's Happy grammar](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/compiler/parser/Parser.y) in its repository.

Comment: Thanks! I think from the Happy's grammar I can figure it out what's going on, but these LALR grammars are so painful. Very surprising that that a Language designed by academics doesn't have a BNF grammar for its extensions!